# Unity3D Third Person Controller and Animations

Tags: unity-game-engine

My problem is that a custom walk animation I have set in the third person controller of Unity3D is not shown.

The animation is imported from a FBX file with the model@walk.fbx structure. I know the animation works, because if I use it as the idle animation it shows. On the other hand, it also doesn't seem to be an issue with the controller script, as it works fine with the prototype character.

It seems that the animation being played is the one selected in the Animation component (which has 'Play Automatically' selected). Any attempts to change the animation from the third person controller work for the prototype character, but not for mine.

I don't have nor want run and jump animations. With the prototype character I set the walk animation on each of those with no adverse effects. The controller doesn't turn off animation this way, seeing that there are no log entries in the console from the third person controller script. The relevant line with the CrossFade call is getting called.

Any clues as to where I could look next? Is it more likely an issue with the controller, or with the animation? Something else completely?

**Update:** Below is the code of my controller. It works fine when I use the sample model of the construction worker that is provided with Unity. The lines with `_animation.CrossFade` are getting called at the expected times. Using `Play` or `Blend` instead doesn't help. There are no errors logged in the console.

For our custom animations however it doesn't work. I am now suspecting the issues lies with the model. Unfortunately I am not at liberty to share a sample of that model. I've asked the animator for further details on how he created the FBX export. Are there any specific settings he needs to use for the model to work in Unity? It remains odd though that the animations do work if I add them indepently to the scene.

```
// Require a character controller to be attached to the same game object
@script RequireComponent(CharacterController)

public var idleAnimation : AnimationClip;
public var walkAnimation : AnimationClip;

public var walkMaxAnimationSpeed : float = 0.75;

private var _animation : Animation;

enum CharacterState {
    Idle = 0,
    Walking = 1,
}

private var _characterState : CharacterState;

// The speed when walking
var walkSpeed = 2.0;
var speedSmoothing = 10.0;
var rotateSpeed = 500.0;

var targetPrecision = 5;
var targetMaxDistance = 200;

// The camera doesnt start following the target immediately but waits for a split second to avoid too much waving around.
private var lockCameraTimer = 0.0;

// The current move direction in x-z
private var moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
// The current x-z move speed
private var moveSpeed = 0.0;

// The last collision flags returned from controller.Move
private var collisionFlags : CollisionFlags; 

// Are we moving backwards (This locks the camera to not do a 180 degree spin)
private var movingBack = false;
// Is the user pressing any keys?
private var isMoving = false;

private var isControllable = true;

private var isTargetting : boolean = false;
private var targetPoint : Vector3 = Vector3.zero;

function Awake () {
    moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

    _animation = GetComponent(Animation);
    if(!_animation)
        Debug.Log("The character you would like to control doesn't have animations. Moving her might look weird.");

    if(!idleAnimation) {
        _animation = null;
        Debug.Log("No idle animation found. Turning off animations.");
    }
    //_animation[idleAnimation.name] = idleAnimation;

    if(!walkAnimation) {
        _animation = null;
        Debug.Log("No walk animation found. Turning off animations.");
    }
    //_animation[walkAnimation.name] = walkAnimation;
}

function UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection () {
    var cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

    // Forward vector relative to the camera along the x-z plane    
    var forward = cameraTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    forward.y = 0;
    forward = forward.normalized;

    // Right vector relative to the camera
    // Always orthogonal to the forward vector
    var right = Vector3(forward.z, 0, -forward.x);

    var v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    var h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    // Are we moving backwards or looking backwards
    if (v < -0.2)
        movingBack = true;
    else
        movingBack = false;

    var wasMoving = isMoving;
    isMoving = Mathf.Abs (h) > 0.1 || Mathf.Abs (v) > 0.1;

    // Target direction relative to the camera
    var targetDirection = h * right + v * forward;

    // Lock camera for short period when transitioning moving & standing still
    lockCameraTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (isMoving != wasMoving)
        lockCameraTimer = 0.0;

    // We store speed and direction seperately,
    // so that when the character stands still we still have a valid forward direction
    // moveDirection is always normalized, and we only update it if there is user input.
    if (targetDirection != Vector3.zero) {
        // If we are really slow, just snap to the target direction
        if (moveSpeed < walkSpeed * 0.9) {
            moveDirection = targetDirection.normalized;
        }
        // Otherwise smoothly turn towards it
        else {
            moveDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(moveDirection, targetDirection, rotateSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad * Time.deltaTime, 1000);
            moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized;
        }
    }

    // Smooth the speed based on the current target direction
    var curSmooth = speedSmoothing * Time.deltaTime;

    // Choose target speed
    //* We want to support analog input but make sure you cant walk faster diagonally than just forward or sideways
    var targetSpeed = Mathf.Min(targetDirection.magnitude, 1.0);

    _characterState = CharacterState.Idle;

    // Pick speed modifier
    targetSpeed *= walkSpeed;
    _characterState = CharacterState.Walking;

    moveSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(moveSpeed, targetSpeed, curSmooth);
}


function UpdateTargettedMovementDirection () {
    var cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

    var wasMoving = isMoving;
    isMoving = true;//Mathf.Abs (h) > 0.1 || Mathf.Abs (v) > 0.1;

    // Target direction relative to the camera
    // var targetDirection = h * right + v * forward;
    var targetDirection = Vector3.zero;
    targetDirection.x =  targetPoint.x - transform.position.x;
    targetDirection.z =  targetPoint.z - transform.position.z;
    targetDirection = targetDirection.normalized;
    //Debug.Log("Target direction is " + targetDirection);

    // Lock camera for short period when transitioning moving & standing still
    lockCameraTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (isMoving != wasMoving)
        lockCameraTimer = 0.0;

    // We store speed and direction seperately,
    // so that when the character stands still we still have a valid forward direction
    // moveDirection is always normalized, and we only update it if there is user input.
    if (targetDirection != Vector3.zero) {
        // If we are really slow, just snap to the target direction
        if (moveSpeed < walkSpeed * 0.9) {
            moveDirection = targetDirection.normalized;
        }
        // Otherwise smoothly turn towards it
        else {
            moveDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(moveDirection, targetDirection, rotateSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad * Time.deltaTime, 1000);
            moveDirection = moveDirection.normalized;
        }
    }

    // Smooth the speed based on the current target direction
    var curSmooth = speedSmoothing * Time.deltaTime;

    // Choose target speed
    //* We want to support analog input but make sure you cant walk faster diagonally than just forward or sideways
    var targetSpeed = Mathf.Min(targetDirection.magnitude, 1.0);

    _characterState = CharacterState.Idle;

    // Pick speed modifier
    targetSpeed *= walkSpeed;
    _characterState = CharacterState.Walking;

    moveSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(moveSpeed, targetSpeed, curSmooth);      
}

function Update() {
    if (!isControllable) {
        // kill all inputs if not controllable.
        Input.ResetInputAxes();
    }

    var distance : float = 0;
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
        if (isTargetting) {
            isTargetting = false;
            // Debug.Log("Stopped moving");
            FaceCamera();
        } else {
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            var layerMask = 1 << 8; // Terrain is layer 8
            var hit : RaycastHit;
            Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, ray.direction, hit, 1000, layerMask);
            distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, hit.point);
            if (distance <= targetMaxDistance && hit.point != Vector3.zero) {
                targetPoint = hit.point;
                isTargetting = true;
                // Debug.Log("Mouse up at hit " + hit.point + " at distance " + distance);
            } else {
                isTargetting = false;
                // Debug.Log("Ignored mouse up at hit " + hit.point + " at distance " + distance);
            }
        }
    }

    if (isTargetting) {
        // Debug.Log("Moving to " + targetPoint);
        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPoint);
        if (distance < targetPrecision) {
            // Debug.Log("Reached point " + targetPoint + " at distance " + distance);
            isTargetting = false;
            FaceCamera();
        } else {
            UpdateTargettedMovementDirection();
        }
    } else {
        UpdateSmoothedMovementDirection();
    }

    // Calculate actual motion
    var movement = moveDirection * moveSpeed;
    movement *= Time.deltaTime;

    // Move the controller
    var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
    collisionFlags = controller.Move(movement);

    // ANIMATION sector
    if (_animation) {       
        if (controller.velocity.sqrMagnitude < 0.1) {
            _animation.CrossFade(idleAnimation.name);
        } else {
            //_animation[walkAnimation.name].speed = Mathf.Clamp(controller.velocity.magnitude, 0.0, walkMaxAnimationSpeed);
            _animation.CrossFade(walkAnimation.name);       
        }
    } else {
         Debug.Log("Animation is null!");
    }
    // ANIMATION sector

    // Set rotation to the move direction
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
}

function OnControllerColliderHit (hit : ControllerColliderHit ) {
//  Debug.DrawRay(hit.point, hit.normal);
    if (hit.moveDirection.y > 0.01) 
        return;
}

function GetSpeed () {
    return moveSpeed;
}

function GetDirection () {
    return moveDirection;
}

function IsMovingBackwards () {
    return movingBack;
}

function GetLockCameraTimer () {
    return lockCameraTimer;
}

function IsMoving () : boolean {
    return Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) + Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) > 0.5;
}

function Reset () {
    gameObject.tag = "Player";
}

function FaceCamera() {
    var cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

    // Forward vector relative to the camera along the x-z plane    
    var forward = cameraTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
    forward.y = 0;
    forward = forward.normalized;

    moveDirection = -forward;
}
```

**Update 2:** The settings used to create the animations are in these screenshots. Are they correct?
[image: Animation export setting 1] 
[image: Animation export setting 2]

Comment: Which version of Unity3D do you use? Did I understand you right that you have 1 file for the model and all animations are stored in their own files anim1@model.fbx, anim2@model.fbx? What is shown in the inspector after adding the model to the scene i.e. are all animations listed in the animations array?

Comment: @Kay Unity3D 3.5.2f2, so the latest version. I have model.fbx and model@idle.fbx and model@walk.fbx. They show up as 3 separate files in the Inspector. When I drag model.fbx into the scene, it contains the animations 'Take 001' (default, not sure where this one came from), 'idle' and 'walk'. (Another model I tried this with had the 'idle' animation missing.) I have tried correcting that list in the inspector by setting the expected animations.

Answer (score 1):

Not (yet :-) an answer but I need more space and images.

Since 3.5 Unity3d the way to handle imports based on animation@model.fbx notation has changed and some people reported trouble (s. for example [BIG Unity 3.5.0f1 problem with Skinned Rig - Major FAIL](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/122494-BIG-Unity-3.5.0f1-problem-with-Skinned-Rig-Major-FAIL)). The problem arises when a 2nd root bone comes to play but I could solve this by dragging the animations to the model file prefab (most of my animations are contained in the model and the remaining 2 are no big pain).

Just to be really sure that I understood your answer in the comments section right, you have something like this:

[image]

That means:

- Within the character model the animations array contains all animations
- The number of bones and all names are exactly like in your prototype character
- If you open an animation view, you can see a read-only list of all animations of the character selected in hierarchy view

Assuming this is fine some more suggestions:

- I can't see any place in the code where you set [WrapMode.Loop](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/WrapMode.Loop.html?from=Animation) or animation speed. Are you sure it is configured as Loop in inspector and is not overwritten somewhere.
- CrossFade with no parameters assumes 0.3 seconds
- What happens after the cross fade call? Does the DefaulTake stops playing?
- Can you drag the Walk animation as default
- Do you use different animation layers?
- What output do you get when you set up `Debug.Log ("Walk: " + player.animation.IsPlaying ("Walk"));`

---

**[Update]**

1. Let's look at the import settings. Do you have *Split Animations*
   checked and are there maybe wrong values entered at *Start* and
   *End* like 1-1?

   [image: Animation Import Settings]
2. Regarding *Toggling of IsPlaying*: Please create more output about the [AnimationState](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/AnimationState.html) properties. Most notable speed, length, enabled, weight, ... I have a suspicion that the animation is too short or played too fast.
3. A walk animation that is no bone animation sounds a bit strange. On the other hand console would cry out loud if bone names are not matching. So I assume there is no problem now.

Comment: • The 3rd person controller and the model both contain the Animation component, and contain the animations. I've turned off 'play automatically', which means that now also the idle animation doesn't play (despite the CrossFade call). • The bones and their names are not the same, but as I understood it this isn't a bone controller animation, so does that really matter? • The animation view does contain the read-only list of animations. • I've set the loop mode during the import. I'll try resetting it in my script. • With 'play automatically' off, no animation play at all. • Don't use layers.

Comment: I tried your debug statement. That gives something interesting: it toggles between True and False repeatedly during the time it should be playing.

Comment: ad 1) I've asked the animator to re-export the animation with the settings I found [here](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Importing_and_Exporting_Models_(Maya)), but he is taking his sweet time. :-( Currently not splitting the animation, but importing different model@animation.fbx files.

Comment: ad 2) I am a bit confused now about the difference between Animation and AnimationClip. It seems I'm dealing with AnimationClips here. The walk animation logs a length of 8.08333 and frameRate of 24 fps. The wrap mode is Loop and the local bounds are "Center: (0.1, 3.2, -0.1), Extents: (1.5, 3.4, 2.0)" BTW, discard the toggling behavior. That was just me being dumb: there were two controllers logging at the same time.

Comment: ad 3) The walk animation is key frame based, it is not done by me controlling the bones. Though I'm pretty sure that's how the animator did create the key frame animation in Maya.

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty as you've been quite helpful. Thank you! I hope you can give one more look at my latest comments to see if there is still something that I can do to get this to work.

Comment: @johan: Very generous, thanks:) Re 2) You're right, these are all AnimationClips. Animation is the 'container' for all clips and every clip has at least 1 AnimationState returned by Animation["clipName"]. If PlayQueued() is called, a copy of the default AnimationState is returned and has to be used for this special clip (will be invalidated when clip is finished).

Comment: Re 3) I think key frame based is the default and the frames are an integral part of the clip while baked animations are not recommended. Do you see the animation curves (read-only) for all bones  in [Animation View](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Animation.html)? I've currently no access to my dev-Mac, so I'm not sure if this works: A) Can you play the animation within the animation view using Play button B) Try to create a simple but visible bone animation in Unity's animation view and use this instead

Answer (score 0):

That is strange, can you post the source&demo?

You can try to check:

1. Check if the animation names and properties are set correctly in the editor.
2. Create an object without the controller and make sure the animations were imported correctly.